# glfwInit() causes access violation

Tags: glfw

```
#include <glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run glfwInit() it throws an access violation and says "Frame not in module". [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vb9.png)

Comment: Which Compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown because the error is produced in a non debuggable source code.

The most probable cause is that DLL was not loaded.

Try to add GLFW bin path to one of the PATH environment variable, or copy DLL to executable path .

Try calling glfwGetVersion to check DLL is loaded before call glfwInit.

```
int major;
int minor;
int rev;
glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev) ;
cout << major << "." << minor << "." << rev<< endl;
```

Comment: I have put the glfw3.dll in the same folder as the exe already. Where would I find the GLFW Bin Path to add to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: It's enough If you have put in the same folder. Have you tried to call glfwGetVersion()? What is the result?

Comment: I am not sure how to use glfwGetVersion(), what do I put in for the parameters?

Comment: Added to solution

Comment: It just logged "3.3.0"

Comment: Then DLL is loaded